# Will ifndef always work on an object-like macro defined with an empty replacement-list

Tags: c, c99, c-preprocessor, include-guards

[Include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in header files are often used to protect sections of code from double inclusion:

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_H
#define FOOBAR_H

extern void myfoofunc(void);

#endif
```

Include guards typically rely on the expectation that if an object-like macro was already defined, the lines within the `#ifndef` block will not included -- thus avoiding double inclusion.

I've noticed that the `#define` line for many include headers have empty replacement-lists. Does the C99 standard guarantee that object-like macros defined with an empty replacement-list will be considered "defined" by `#ifndef`?

When describing the syntax of `#define`, the C99 standard seems to imply that a replacement-list is required in **section 6.10.3 paragraph 9**:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> **# define** *identifier replacement-list new-line*
>
> defines an *object-like macro* that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name to be
>   replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that
>   constitute the remainder of the directive. The replacement list is
>   then rescanned for more macro names as specified below.

Does this mean include headers should instead be of the form: `#define FOOBAR_H 1`?

Comment: "the C99 standard seems to imply that a replacement-list is required " -- It does no such thing. Take a look at the definition of replacement-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard syntax production for a `replacement-list` is: `pp-tokens [opt]`. So no tokens are necessary for a replacement-list to be valid.

So `#ifdef` will work fine and as expected for macros that are defined 'empty'.  A ton of code depends on this.

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked the *Syntax* listing in **section 6.10 paragraph 1**: `replacement-list` is defined as `pp-tokens [opts]` as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. The replacement list may well be empty. `#define FOO` means that `defined FOO` is true, but `FOO` is replaced with nothing.

Example:

```
#define FOO
#define BAR 1

#if defined FOO && defined BAR
int a = FOO + BAR ;
#endif
```

Result of preprocessing:

```
int a = + 1 ;
```

Comment: In this case, would `#if FOO == 1` succeed, or is the actual numerical value of `FOO` implementation defined?

Comment: The value of `FOO` is the empty string.

Comment: Does this mean the I'd get a compiler error if I use `#if` to try to compare it to a numerical value?

Comment: @VilhelmGray: You would. (Why aren't you trying this out yourself?!)

Comment: I wasn't certain if this was just affecting my compiler, or should occur on all standard compliant compilers. For prosterity, I decided to verify this for C99 compliant compilers. In **section 6.10.1 paragraph 1**: `the resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of 6.6`. So after macro replacement to an empty string we'd have `#if == 1`, thus leading to an improper constant expression and thus a compiler error on all C99 compliant compilers.

Comment: Oops, that should be "posterity" not "prosperity" in my original post. :P

Comment: @VilhelmGray "In this case, would #if FOO == 1 succeed" -- That expands to `#if == 1`. "the actual numerical value of FOO" -- there is no such thing ... the preprocessor does textual/token expansion.

Comment: Posterity already has the C standard, it doesn't need quotations from it in SO comment threads.

Comment: @JimBalter So does that mean that `#if FOO == 1` may be valid on certain compilers?

Comment: @VilhelmGray I have no idea why you would think that or how you could possibly get that from anything I wrote. FOO has an empty replacement-list, therefore "#if FOO == 1" expands to "#if == 1", which is a syntax error ... all of this is unambiguously specified by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

No; the macro substitution will not take place in the `#ifndef` line. If it did, then the whole statement would be a syntax error (since there wouldn't be anything following the `#ifndef`).

I think I've actually seen some instances of `#define FOOBAR_H 1` but that's more of a personal taste.